# How do I disable emergency call after three power button clicks on my Samsung S10?

Tags: samsung, android-10, buttons, magisk, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S10 (on Android 10). One of the features that constantly irritates me is the accidental dialling of the emergency number. The system by-default looks for triple power button tap and automatically dials the emergency number (112). I read on XDA here that this is a feature specific to India and Indian SIMs, and I also bought this in India and used an Indian SIM for a short while during my stay there, but have since switched with no effect on the issue. Other regional users, per some threads of Samsung subreddit and Samsung forums, do not have this problem.

How do I change this behaviour? I'm looking to prevent emergency number dial on triple power button tap, and if possible, please provide a non-root based solution. I am willing to install Magisk, but only if there is a definite solution, and no alternative, as it adds another layer of complication. Thank you!